# Exit application from android hardware back button in phonegap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, back-button

Is there a way to show a confirmation popup when you press the hardware back button in android devices to exit the phonegap/ionic application?

In the current status, my app keep going to the previous state upon clicking the back button.

Is there a way to exit the app when you press the back button no matter where you are on, in the application?

I found this piece of code but it did not seem to work:

```js
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Sign Out Confirm',
        template: 'Are you sure you want to Logout?'
    });
    confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
        if (res) {
            $rootScope.rootScopeUserTransactionPassword = null;
            $state.go('app.playlists');
        } else {
            console.log('You are not sure');
        }
    });
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // EDIT
  navigator.app.exitApp(); // exit the app
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Inside the head tag of your index.html file you can place this code inside <script></script> tag.

Comment: this code will make you to get out of app from all the screens. you gotta do some modifications, if you dont wanna get out of app except home screen.

Comment: Check the answer. I have added one line. Tell me if it is not helping.

Answer (score 2):

It will ask you before exit in stipulated timestamp : Press back button again to exit. If it's dashboard page then it will ask whether to Log out? 
I hope it will solve your problem.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory){
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
            if ($ionicHistory.currentView().stateName == 'dashboard') {
                Dialogs.showConfirm('Do you want to logout?', function(buttonIndex) {
                    if (buttonIndex == 1)
                        User.clear();
                }, 'Logout', ['Yes', 'No']);
            } else

            if ($rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit) {
                ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            } else if ($ionicHistory.backView()) {
                $ionicHistory.goBack();
            } else {
                $rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit = true;
                window.plugins.toast.showShortCenter(
                    "Press back button again to exit",
                    function(a) {},
                    function(b) {}
                );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $rootScope.backButtonPressedOnceToExit = false;
                }, 2000);
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }, 101);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following close the app if we hit back button on Android device in "Login" screen. 
In your app.js you maybe have something like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url : '/',
}).state('login', {
    url : '/login',
    views : {
        contentView : {
            templateUrl : 'login.html',
            controller : 'LoginCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

So all you have to do is add this method in the same file:

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
        if ($state.current.name == "login") {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Note that "login" it the state name which mentioned in the app.config

Comment: How to write this if I am doing this using Cordova and not ionic?